# How to find all the available values of an option?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, vscodium

VS Codium allows users to configure options by using their name in a config file. However, it's not always obvious what the supported values are for a given name, and it's not always spelled out in the documentation either.

For example, the option `security.workspace.trust.banner`. I imagine this can be set to `always` or `never`, but I have no way of knowing for sure (without tedious trial and error). Note that the question is not about `security.workspace.trust.banner` but about finding out the legal values of **any option**.

Is there a reliable way to find out what exact values are acceptable for an option, given its name, for **every option**? Or do you ultimately have to guess?

Comment: If it isn't an extension-contributed setting, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_languagespecific-editor-settings  Do you not get intellisense for the options when you type `"security.workspace.trust.banner": "|"` with the cursor at the pipe?  And then Ctrl+space to expand the description of each setting option.

Comment: I do get the intellisense suggestions. I was wondering if there's a place where they're listed.

Comment: I think only the link I showed, but it is the same info as the intellisense.

Comment: @Mark I think that's close enough - if you post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Also see the command `Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)` - same info as link I assume.  Thanks on the acceptance but I assume this has been asked before.

Comment: it is specified in the `package.json` file of the extension, you specify the scheme of the option, if no scheme given you have to read the doc page of the extension or VSC, and a last possibility is reading the source code, but some extension are big